# Asp.net Call Code Behind with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

since i didn´t find any solution that helped me, i thought i asked.
I need a JavaScriptfunction with calls a method in my code-behind, and since i´m really new to this, i dont understand what am i doing wrong.
On my Master Page (Site.Master) i enabled PageMethods:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

And in the Content of my Page i have put the Script:

```
        function reply_click(clicked_id) {
            alert(clicked_id);
            PageMethods.javascriptTest(clicked_id);
```

And now my method in the code-behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void javascriptTest(int buttonID)
    {

        Test2.Text += buttonID + "***";

        // Use the ID for DB access

    }
```

I need that ID for later, when i have to do stuff in my database, but i´m always getting PageMethods undefined errors and i dont know why :/

EDIT: The Solution was indeed to make the WebMethod static, i just made a workaround, so i could use all the details i need for my db access

JavaScript:

```
    function reply_click(clicked_id, clicked_name) {
        // Schulungsdaten holen
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%= SignGridView.ClientID %>");
        var row = grid.rows[0];
        var appointmentData = row.cells[clicked_id].innerText;
        // Userdaten holen
        var userID = document.getElementById("<%= UserData.ClientID %>").innerText;
        PageMethods.javaScriptUserSignIn(appointmentData, userID, clicked_name, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
        location.reload();
        }

        function OnSucceeded(response) {
            alert(response);
        }

        function OnFailed(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
```

Code-Behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string javaScriptUserSignIn(string appointmentData, string userID, string status)
    {
        string result = "";
        SignIn sign = new SignIn();
        result = sign.SignToTraining(appointmentData, userID, status);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the clicked_id as a parameter to PageMethods.javascriptTest(); ?

Comment: yeah forgot that, but thats not the issue!but thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascriptTest method needs to be static

Try This:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void javascriptTest(int buttonID)
{
      Test2.Text += buttonID + "***";
      // Use the ID for DB access
}
```